# Reloading NSTableView data is not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I was trying to update `NSTableView` in my application, but nothing I've found worked.
I have two classes in my project:

- `AppDelegate`
- `TableViewController` which is `NSTableViewDelegate` and
  `NSTableViewDataSource`.

When I try to add new row I can see that `ArrayController` (which provides data to table), contains new element but `NSTableView` doesn't.
My table is also connected as property to `TableViewController` but it isn't connected with `AppDelegate`.
I've tried to call

`[self.table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

and

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.table reloadData];
});
```

Where `table` is NSTableView connected property.

Is there any other method to refresh table view?

**EDIT**

**Problem solved.**

Comment: How did you solve it? Having the same since switching to OSX 10.9.

Comment: In `AppDelegate` I have created `NSObject` outlet and connected `TableViewController`to it in my `.xib` file, then from `AppDelegate` I can call its methods, it worked for me.

Comment: Hhmmm, dont quite understand what you mean with "... then from AppDelegate I can call its methods ...". In my controller I call **[[self tableView] reloadData];** when I get new data in. In OSX 10.8, my table view was updated automatically, now under 10.9 it only gets updated when I resize the window for example.

Comment: I've written additional `IBAction` in my controller where I have `[myTable reloadData]` and from `AppDelegate` I call that `IBAction` method

Comment: I'm working on 10.9 as You, in my case `AppDelegate` performs it with some time interval

Comment: ok, understand, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is the place that you are adding the data to your array in TableViewController? If so, did you try adding [self.table reloadData] by itself right after you add the data to your array? That should get the updated data without the methods you have wrapped it in. The performSelector and dispatch_async methods seem unnecessary, but since I can't see all the code, you may have them there for a reason that is not apparent.

Comment: Yes I have added `NSArrayController` that provides data for columns to my class as a `IBOutlet`, I tried to call `[selt.table reloadData]` but it didn't help. I can post my whole code in few hours when I come back from work.